# How to define my RNN Cell in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to define my own RNN cell in tensorflow 2.0, which first concatenates the previous state and the input into a vector, and then stack several RNN layers to finally obtain the output. I defined the RNN cell by following the MinimalRNNCell example in tensorflow instructions, but it does not work. Could you please help me with my codes?

My code is shown as follows:

```
class FCNNRNNCell(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        self.output_size = units
        super(FCNNRNNCell,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.fcnn1 = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], 12),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='fcnn1')
        self.bias1 = self.add_weight(shape=(12),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='fcnn1')
        self.fcnn2 = self.add_weight(shape=(12, 12),
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='fcnn1')
        self.bias2 = self.add_weight(shape=(12),
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='fcnn1')
        self.fcnn3 = self.add_weight(shape=(12, self.units),
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='fcnn1')
        self.bias3 = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units),
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='fcnn1')
        self.built = True
    def call(self,inputs,states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        x = tf.concat((inputs, prev_output), axis=-1)
        x = K.dot(x, self.fcnn1) + self.bias1
        x = tf.keras.activations.linear(x)
        x = K.dot(x, self.fcnn2) + self.bias2
        x = tf.keras.activations.relu(x)
        x = K.dot(x, self.fcnn3) + self.bias3
        x = tf.keras.activations.linear(x)
        return h, [h]
```

I test the cell by the following trail:

```
cell = FCNNRNNCell(4)
x = tf.keras.Input((None,5))
layer = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell)
y = layer(x)
```

and then I got the following error:

```
2019-12-22 13:40:07.750340: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2019-12-22 13:40:07.750738: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 8. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2019-12-22 13:40:07.760843: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:76 : Invalid argument: shape must be a vector of {int32,int64}, got shape []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cc/Documents/CloudStationN/Scientific-Works-Windows/Computing Programs/Machine Learning/Quantum_RNN/Classical RNN Ising Model Dynamics.py", line 152, in <module>
    y = layer(x)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 623, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 817, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2141, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 544, in build
    self.cell.build(step_input_shape)
  File "/Users/cc/Documents/CloudStationN/Scientific-Works-Windows/Computing Programs/Machine Learning/Quantum_RNN/Classical RNN Ising Model Dynamics.py", line 121, in build
    name='fcnn1')
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 522, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 744, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 139, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 258, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 219, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2507, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1406, in __init__
    distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1537, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 119, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 253, in __call__
    self.maxval, dtype)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 800, in random_uniform
    shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 245, in random_uniform
    rnd = gen_random_ops.random_uniform(shape, dtype, seed=seed1, seed2=seed2)
  File "/Users/cc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_random_ops.py", line 812, in random_uniform
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: shape must be a vector of {int32,int64}, got shape [] [Op:RandomUniform]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace return h, [h] by return x, [x] in the quest. However, the error information is the same.